# LazyVGrid cell subviews keep disappearing for particular text inside cell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid

### Scenario

I am trying to create a 3 columned LazyVGrid which displays items having an icon and a text via a LazyVGrid.

### Code

```
struct CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let image: Image
    let color: Color
}

extension CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel, rhs: CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}

struct CategoriesListView: View {
    let categorySelectionDatasource: [CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel]
    let gridItemLayout: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 3)
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 40) {
                ForEach((0..<categorySelectionDatasource.count)) {
                    let category = categorySelectionDatasource[$0]
                    VStack {
                        category.image
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(category.color)
                        Text(category.name)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CategoriesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let dumyCategory = [CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel(name: "Household", image: Image(systemName: "house.fill"), color: .green),
                            CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel(name: "Finance", image: Image(systemName: "banknote.fill"), color: .green), CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel(name: "Education", image: Image(systemName: "book.fill"), color: .purple), CategoryPickerCellPresentationModel(name: "Health", image: Image(systemName: "cross.case.fill"), color: .red)]
        CategoriesListView(categorySelectionDatasource: dumyCategory+dumyCategory.reversed()+dumyCategory)
    }
}
```

### Problem

Whenever the text is `Health`, I try to scroll the grid, the text disappears. I tried a couple of different texts other than `Health`, it works great for them.

[image]

What could be a possible cause for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is issue of `frame` remove this line `.frame(width: 50, height: 50)` and it works. it is not problem with letter `Health` but it generate same issue when `text` width less than 50.

**Edit**

if you add `id` in ForEach loop, works. no need to remove frame.

```
ForEach((0..<categorySelectionDatasource.count), id:\.self)
```

Comment: Thanks, Dhaval. It is strange though how come SwiftUI did not clip or truncate the text rather than making it disappeared. I felt it to be an issue of reusability and optimization.

Comment: Even in the implementation, the data models are conforming to identifiable. SwiftUI needs the data models to be identifiable or else excepts you to pass an explicit id as you have done. So both should ideally do the job. Do you find any difference?